# what do the parameters uid and gid with /etc/fstab do?

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs, uid

I'm mounting directories. I wrote the needed lines to `/etc/fstab`.I'm using `cifs` protocoll.

**I wonder what the parameters `uid` and `gid` do**, since they're similar for any user. (So this can't be any user id.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mount options for Microsoft (and similar) file systems to set the owner and group**

From `man mount`,

```
Mount options for fat
       (Note:  fat  is  not  a  separate  filesystem,  but a common part of the
       msdos, umsdos and vfat filesystems.)

       ...

       uid=value and gid=value
              Set the owner and group of all  files.   (Default:  the  uid  and
              gid  of  the  current process.)
```

There is a similar text for `ntfs`. See the following link for examples, where `uid` is used,

[How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072?s=4|14.2986#956072)